# Always shows 404 php basic routing

Tags: php, url-routing

I tried to create a basic routing with MVC, but when you view any page it displays the correct content meaning it pulls in the view. But 404 always displays.
correct content will show based on the URL such as home page, but also 404 and something went wrong in addition. Even through the Route is correct. I did not include the views and controllers as at the moment the controllers is just pulling together the view(head,body and content). It looks like its the Models/Route.php that's the issue.
Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

-index.php

```
  <?php
require_once('Routes.php');

    function __autoload($class_name) {
        if (file_exists('Controllers/'.$class_name.'.php'))
        {
            require_once ('Controllers/'.$class_name.'.php');
        }

        else if (file_exists('Models/'.$class_name.'.php'))
        {
            require_once ('Models/'.$class_name.'.php');
        }

    }?>
```

Routes.php

```
<?php
Route::set('index.php', function() 
{
    Index::CreateView('Index');

});

Route::set('home', function() 
{
    Index::CreateView('Index');

});
?>
```

Models/Route.php

```
<?php

class Route
{

    public static $validRoutes = array();

    public static function set($route, $function)
    {
        self::$validRoutes[] = $route;

        if ($_GET['url'] == $route)
        {
            $function->__invoke();

        }elseif(!in_array($_GET['url'], Route::$validRoutes)){
            echo "404";
        }else{
            echo "something went wrong";
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Since PHP 5.1 you should be using `spl_autoload_register()`. Also, these day most of the people use PSR-4 autoloader implementations. As for what you do with the routing ... emm .. where did you find the time machine of in 2005?

Comment: tereško thank you for responding, I was looking tutorials online mostly You tube. Can you point me in a better direct of Routing? Tutorials etc?